# NextJS: warning Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to add this Sidebar to my Dashboard but I get an error stating:

> react_devtools_backend.js:2528 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a >component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, >or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

I don't see the infinite loop in my code, can anyone help?

Page code:

```
import styles from "../../styles/Home.module.css";
// import OrganizerNavigation from "../../components/organizer-layout/OrganizerNavigation";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Dashboard from "../../components/organizer-layout/Dashboard";
import Footer from "../../components/layout/Footer";
import MainNavigation from "../../components/layout/MainNavigation";
import DashboardSidebar from "../../components/Sidebar/Sidebar";

export default function Organizer() {
  const [dashboardSelected, setDashboardSelected] = useState(false);
  const setDashboardSelectedHandler = (x) => {
    setDashboardSelected(x);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {/* <OrganizerNavigation /> */}
      <MainNavigation />
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <DashboardSidebar var0={setDashboardSelectedHandler} />
        {/* <Dashboard /> */}
        {dashboardSelected && <div>hola</div>}
        
      </div>

      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

DashboardSidebar component code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import StylishSidebar from "stylish-sidebar";

const Sidebar = (props) => {
  // const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);

  const colorPalette = {
    bgColor1: "#ffffff",
    bgColor2: "#ffffff",
    fontColor: "rgba(161, 161, 161)",
    fontColorSelected: "#000000",
    dividerColor: "#434D56",
    selectedBackgroundCollapsedMode: "light",
  };

  const fonts = {
    header: "Architects Daughter",
    menu: "Poppins",
  };

  const header = {
    fullName: "",
    shortName: "",
  };

  const backgroundImage = {
    url: "",
    showImage: false,
  };

  const menuItems = [
    {
      name: "Dashboard",
      to: "/organizer",
      icon: "/icons/graph3.svg",
      subMenuItems: [],
    },
    {
      name: "My Events",
      to: "/organizer/my-events",
      icon: "/icons/blog.svg",
      subMenuItems: [],
    },
    {
      name: "New Event",
      to: "/organizer/create-event",
      icon: "/icons/plus.svg",
      subMenuItems: [],
    },
    {
      name: "Calendar",
      to: "/organizer/calendar",
      icon: "/icons/keypad.svg",
      subMenuItems: [],
    },
    {
      name: "Total Orders",
      to: "/organizer/total-orders",
      icon: "/icons/graph1.svg",
      subMenuItems: [],
    },
    {
      name: "Customers",
      to: "/organizer/customer-list",
      icon: "/icons/about.svg",
      subMenuItems: [],
    },
    {
      name: "Settings",
      to: "/organizer/settings",
      icon: "/icons/helm.svg",
      subMenuItems: [],
    },
  ];

  // const router = useRouter();

  const handleMenuItemClick = (event, index) => {
    // menuItems[index].to
    console.log(index);
    if (index == 0) {
      props.var0(true);
    }
    // else if (menuItems[index].to == 1) {
    //   props.var0(true);
    // } else if (menuItems[index].to == 2) {
    //   props.var0(true);
    // } else if (menuItems[index].to == 3) {
    //   props.var0(true);
    // } else if (menuItems[index].to == 4) {
    //   props.var0(true);
    // } else if (menuItems[index].to == 5) {
    //   props.var0(true);
    // } else if (menuItems[index].to == 6) {
    //   props.var0(true);
    // }
  };

  // const handleSubMenuItemClick = (menuItemIndex, subMenuItemIndex) => {
  // router.push(
  //   `${menuItems[menuItemIndex].to}${menuItems[menuItemIndex].subMenuItems[subMenuItemIndex].to}`
  // );
  // };

  return (
    <StylishSidebar
      // backgroundImage={backgroundImage}
      colorPalette={colorPalette}
      useImageAsHeader={false}
      header={header}
      fonts={fonts}
      menuItems={menuItems}
      widthExpanded={"20%"}
      widthCollapsed={"5%"}
      minWidth={"80px"}
      maxWidth={"280px"}
      isOpen={isOpen}
      showToggler={false}
      // onTogglerClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}
      // onHeaderClick={() => history.push("editor")}
      onMenuItemClick={handleMenuItemClick}
      // onSubMenuItemClick={handleSubMenuItemClick}
    />
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

I tried commenting the DashboardSidebar component and it stopped. Could be a problem of the library and not mine?

Comment: Is the console logging the value of index many times from `handleMenuItemClick`?

Comment: @anolan23 nope.

Comment: Are you sure that `onMenuItemClick` accepts parameters?

Comment: Try removing the `index` param from `handleMenuItemClick` and just `console.log(event)` or something inside of that function. Just to see if it fixes the error.

Comment: @anolan23 `onMenuItemClick` accepts params.

Comment: @anolan23 this is the `console.log(event)` result: `SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: 'onClick', _targetInst: null, type: 'click', nativeEvent: PointerEvent, target: p.css-1wnvjz2, …}`

Comment: You said everything works fine if you comment out `<DashboardSidebar var0={setDashboardSelectedHandler} />`?

Comment: Make sure you're importing the right file: `import DashboardSidebar from "../../components/Sidebar/Sidebar";`

Comment: The npm package only has 17 weekly downloads so it may have to do with that